# Does Single observable provide API to set timer and interval?

Tags: android, observable, rx-java, rx-android, reactivex

I have been using Single observable with RxJava for network task. I have seen that Observable type provides APIs for setting timer and intervals as in the following example.

```
Observable.interval(0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .take(5)
    .flatMap {
        return@flatMap Observable.create<String> { emitter ->
            emitter.onNext("Hello, me")
            emitter.onComplete()
        }
    }
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe {
        Log.d("IntervalExample", it)
    }
```

Does Single type also provide similar APIs? I could use Observable type but I am currently restricted to use only Single type. I have searched for documentations online, but could not find anything useful. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "use only Single type"? [Here](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#method.summary) is the method of the available operators for `Single`: there is `timer` but no `interval` because it makes no sense when there can be only one success value.

Answer (score 0):

The `Single` type has a [`delaySubscription`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#delaySubscription-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-io.reactivex.Scheduler-) method which may suit your needs

```
Single.create(emitter -> emitter.onSuccess("Hello, me"))
.delaySubscription(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```